# redirect old dynamic urls to seo friendly urls through htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have looked through the other posted questions and I cant seem to find an answer that pertains to my specific situation. I have already established dynamic urls (rr.php?rrid=5) and I am switching over to seo friendly urls (rr/5/name/) I have that part working

```
RewriteRule ^rr/([0-9]+)/([a-z\+\-]+)/?$ /rr.php?rrid=$1 [L]
```

The problem I am having is implementing a 301 redirect to tell the search engines that the urls have changed without causing a redirect loop. Also, I have hundreds of rrid=# and I would like a way to do the 301 similar to the above rule where the /name/ portion is different depending on the rrid=#

I know there is a way to add &rewrite to the above rule but I cant figure out how to write the  301 redirect without having to go through and do each one individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have an additional rule for 301 handling. Place  this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+rr\.php\?rrrid=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /rr/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^rr/([0-9]+)/?$ /rr.php?rrid=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^rr/([0-9]+)/([a-z+-]+)/?$ /rr.php?rrid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: The rrid is always a  number so can the regrex in the condition just be ([0-9+])? Also, I am trying to 301 redirect but you have 302 which is only a temporary redirect. Is there a reason you did that?

Comment: Is there a reason for the 302 instead of a 301?

Comment: No specific reason but it is always better to keep 302 in your testing only when everything looks good then change that to 301. Reason is that 301 is cached aggressively by browsers.

Comment: Ok so this work but the only thing I am concerned about is google flagging me for duplicate content when the old urls are directed to rr/5 and the new urls I have submitted in my sitemap are rr/5/name/. Will they both be indexed or does your solution cover that?

Comment: How are your `rr.php` links looking? Do you have `/rr.php?rrid=123` OR `/rr.php?rrid=$1&name=somename`?

Comment: I have converted all my links to rr/123/name. The name portion is just for seo purposes and does not affect the content on the page. They used to be rr.php?rrid=123

Comment: Ok understood but since there is no name parameter in `/rr.php?rrid=123` therefore 301 rule cannot add any name part to redirected URI.